# Does devtools from chrome work with methods?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I´m doing the tic tac toe exercise from the Odin Project (I´m a begginer with javascript, and programming in general). I have a question about how chrome´s devtools breakpoints work with functions that are called as methods.

```
const gameBoard = (() => {
    const rowNumber = 3;
    const columnNumber = 3;
    const board = [];
    const boardContainer = document.querySelector('#board-container')

    const cell = (row, column) => {
        let value = 0
        const cellRow = row;
        const cellColumn = column;
        const cellID = [cellRow, cellColumn]

        const renderCell = (cell) => {
            const cellDiv = document.createElement('div');
            cellDiv.classList.add('board-cell')
            cellDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                let activePlayer = game.activePlayer
                if (getCellValue(cellRow, cellColumn) == 0) {
                updateCell(e.target, activePlayer)
                game.changeActivePlayer()
                game.checkIfWin(cellID)
                }
            })
            boardContainer.appendChild(cellDiv)
        }

        const updateCell = (cell, player) => {
            cell.classList.add(player.color)
            gameBoard.board[cellRow][cellColumn].value = game.activePlayer.index
        }
        
        return {value, renderCell, updateCell, getCellValue}
    };

    const getCellValue = (cellRow, cellColumn) => {
        return board[cellRow][cellColumn].value
    };

    const changeCellValue = (cellRow, cellColumn, newValue) => {
        board[cellRow][cellColumn].value = newValue
    }

    const createBoard = () => {
        for (let i = 0 ; i < rowNumber ; i++) {
            board[i] = [];
            for (let j = 0 ; j < columnNumber ; j++) {
                const newCell = cell(i,j)
                newCell.renderCell()
                board[i].push(newCell)
            }
        }  
        console.log('Create board se ejecuta')
    };

    const getRow = (index) => {
        return board[index]
    }

    const getColumn = (index) => {
        let column = []
        for (let i = 0 ; i < rowNumber; i++) {
            column.push(board[i][index])
        }
        return column
    }

    const getDiagonal = (sign) => {
        let diagonal = []
        for (let i = 0 ; i < rowNumber ; i++) {
            diagonal.push(board[i*(sign)][i*(sign)])
        }
        return diagonal
    }

    return {
        board,
        createBoard,
        getCellValue,
        changeCellValue,
        cell,
        getRow,
        getColumn,
        getDiagonal,
    };
})();

const player = ((name, index, color) => {
    let score = 0
    return {name, index, score, color};
});


const game = (() => {
   const player1 = player(prompt('Nombre de jugador 1'), 1, 'red')
   const player2 = player(prompt('Nombre de jugador 2'), 2, 'blue')

   let activePlayer = player1

   const changeActivePlayer = () => {
    (game.activePlayer === player1) ? 
    game.activePlayer = player2 : 
    game.activePlayer = player1
   }

   const checkIfWin = (cell) => {
    let row = gameBoard.getRow(cell[0])
    let column = gameBoard.getColumn(cell[1])
    const checkEqualValues = (line) => {
        let firstElement = line[0]
        for (let i = 0 ; i < line.length ; i++) {
            if (firstElement.value !== line[i].value) {
                return false
            } 
        }
        return true
    }
    return checkEqualValues(row) || checkEqualValues(column) 
    || checkEqualValues(gameBoard.getDiagonal(1)) || checkEqualValues(gameBoard.getDiagonal(-1))
    ? console.log('alguien gano') 
    : null
   }

   return {
    player1,
    player2,
    activePlayer,
    changeActivePlayer,
    checkIfWin,
   }
    
})();

gameBoard.createBoard()
game.changeActivePlayer()
```

The thing is: When I call my function as a method, and a place a breakpoint there, for example in line 21, and then a click on a cell, the event works, the breakpoint works, but it doesn´t show me the step by step of the function checkIfWin(), it just runs the functions and goes to the next step. And if I place the breakpoint on line 105, and then click on a cell, the breakpoint doesn´t work at all. I can make it work by writing debugger in my code, but I was wondering if it would be possible to make it work with breakpoints.

Comment: To step into a function, you have to click the _Step into_ button in the debugger (or press F11). It doesn't stop at line 105 because there you're just defining the function, to stop when you're calling it you have to place the breakpoint inside it, for example on line 106.

Comment: I can´t believe that was the problem. Sorry, im just starting with this and I couldn´t figure out what was I doing wrong. Thank you for your quick answer, I was struggling with this for hours!